# Conversion problem for a deck build using AddRange for my multiplayer Unity card game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I'm working on a card game consisting of 52 unique cards.  Found the article/question at  ([Making Multiple playered Multiplayer Card Game With Mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206781/making-multiple-playered-multiplayer-card-game-with-mirror?newreg=be88c0f14a1c468198df7b6e1cd95340)) which closely matches some of what I'm trying to do. When I use the code below, I can load the Lists for the Cards - i.e. Card aceOfClubs = new Card() - and add the individual Card data to the Series lists - i.e. clubsSeries.Add(aceOfClubs) - but when I get to adding the cards to the deck using "deck.AddRange(clubsSeries);" I get the following error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UnityEngine.GameObject>'

Am I overlooking some obvious mistake on my part?  Thanks...still a C# newbie but couldn't find anything in searching here or Google...

Below PlayerManager Class;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameBoard;
    public GameObject deckPlace;
    public GameObject okeyPlace;
    public GameObject playerArea;

    public List<GameObject> deck = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<Card> hand = new List<Card>();
    public List<Sprite> cardImages = new List<Sprite>();
    public GameObject cardPrefab;

    [Client]
    public override void OnStartClient()
    {
        base.OnStartClient();

        playerArea = GameObject.Find("PlayerArea");
        gameBoard = GameObject.Find("GameBoard");
        deckPlace = GameObject.Find("Deck");
        okeyPlace = GameObject.Find("OkeyPlace");
    }

    [Server]

    public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        //Generating Cards
        #region Generating FirstDeckOfCards

        List<Card> jokers = new List<Card>();

        Card joker = new Card()
        {
            realValue = 1,
            name = "Joker",
            suit = Card.Suit.joker,
            imgSuit = Card.ImageSuit.jokerImg,
            subValue = 0,
            backFace = Card.Color.cream,
            isJoker = true
        };


        List<Card> clubsSeries = new List<Card>();

        //Clubs Series
        Card aceOfClubs = new Card()
        {
            realValue = 1,
            name = "Clubs",
            suit = Card.Suit.clubs,
            imgSuit = Card.ImageSuit.clubsImg,
            subValue = 0,
            backFace = Card.Color.cream
        };

           And So on...

        #region Joker Cards Are Added To Joker List

        jokers.Add(joker);

        #endregion Joker Cards Are Added To Joker List
        #region Joker2 Cards Are Added To Joker List

        jokers2.Add(joker2);

        #endregion Joker2 Cards Are Added To Joker List

        //Clubs Cards Are Added To ClubsSeries List
        #region Clubs Cards Are Added To ClubsSeries List

        clubsSeries.Add(aceOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(twoOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(threeOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(fourOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(fiveOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(sixOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(sevenOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(eightOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(nineOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(tenOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(elevenOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(twelveOfClubs);
        clubsSeries.Add(thirteenOfClubs);

        #endregion Clubs Cards Are Added To ClubsSeries List
        #region Clubs2 Cards Are Added To ClubsSeries List

        clubsSeries2.Add(aceOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(twoOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(threeOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(fourOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(fiveOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(sixOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(sevenOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(eightOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(nineOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(tenOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(elevenOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(twelveOfClubs2);
        clubsSeries2.Add(thirteenOfClubs2);

        #endregion Clubs2 Cards Are Added To ClubsSeries List

        //Diamonds Cards Are Added To DiamondsSeries List
        #region Diamonds Cards Are Added To DiamondsSeries List

        diamondsSeries.Add(aceOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(twoOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(threeOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(fourOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(fiveOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(sixOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(sevenOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(eightOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(nineOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(tenOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(elevenOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(twelveOfDiamonds);
        diamondsSeries.Add(thirteenOfDiamonds);

        #endregion Diamonds Cards Are Added To DiamondsSeries List
        #region Diamonds2 Cards Are Added To DiamondsSeries List

        diamondsSeries2.Add(aceOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(twoOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(threeOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(fourOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(fiveOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(sixOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(sevenOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(eightOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(nineOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(tenOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(elevenOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(twelveOfDiamonds2);
        diamondsSeries2.Add(thirteenOfDiamonds2);

        #endregion Diamonds2 Cards Are Added To DiamondsSeries List

        //Hearts Cards Are Added To HeartsSeries List
        #region Hearts Cards Are Added To HeartsSeries List

        heartsSeries.Add(aceOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(twoOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(threeOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(fourOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(fiveOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(sixOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(sevenOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(eightOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(nineOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(tenOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(elevenOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(twelveOfHearts);
        heartsSeries.Add(thirteenOfHearts);

        #endregion Hearts Cards Are Added To HeartsSeries List
        #region Hearts2 Cards Are Added To HeartsSeries List

        heartsSeries2.Add(aceOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(twoOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(threeOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(fourOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(fiveOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(sixOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(sevenOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(eightOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(nineOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(tenOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(elevenOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(twelveOfHearts2);
        heartsSeries2.Add(thirteenOfHearts2);

        #endregion Hearts2 Cards Are Added To HeartsSeries List

        //Spades Cards Are Added To SpadesSeries List
        #region Spades Cards Are Added To SpadesSeries List

        spadesSeries.Add(aceOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(twoOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(threeOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(fourOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(fiveOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(sixOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(sevenOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(eightOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(nineOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(tenOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(elevenOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(twelveOfSpades);
        spadesSeries.Add(thirteenOfSpades);

        #endregion Spades Cards Are Added To SpadesSeries List       
        #region Spades2 Cards Are Added To SpadesSeries List

        spadesSeries2.Add(aceOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(twoOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(threeOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(fourOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(fiveOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(sixOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(sevenOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(eightOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(nineOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(tenOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(elevenOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(twelveOfSpades2);
        spadesSeries2.Add(thirteenOfSpades2);

        #endregion Spades2 Cards Are Added To SpadesSeries List       

        #region Cards Are Added To Deck

        deck.AddRange(jokers); //Jokers List Is Added To Deck;
        deck.AddRange(clubsSeries); //Clubs Series List Is Added To Deck;
        deck.AddRange(diamondsSeries); //Diamonds Series List Is Added To Deck;
        deck.AddRange(heartsSeries); //Hearts Series List Is Added To Deck;
        deck.AddRange(spadesSeries); //Spades Series List Is Added To Deck;
        
        #endregion Cards Are Added To Deck

    }
}

[System.Serializable]

public class Card
{
    public int realValue;
    public enum Suit { joker, clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades, okeySuit }
    public Suit suit;
    public enum ImageSuit { jokerImg, clubsImg, diamondsImg, heartsImg, spadesImg }
    public ImageSuit imgSuit;
    public int subValue;
    public enum Color { cream, blue }
    public Color backFace;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `deck.AddRange(clubsSeries)` `deck` is a `List<GameObject>` and `clubSeries` is a `List<Card>`. So you are trying to add `Card` objects to the collection that is working with the `GameObject`.

Is there any reason why your `hand` is a `List<Card>`, but the deck is a `List<GameObject>`?

Comment: I was just following the existing code.  But your question was a good one.  Missed that obvious disparity in types.  This fixed it, so thanks @Morion :)